# How to encrypt string in Java using Windows DPAPI using the system context instead of the user context?

Tags: java, security, encryption, dpapi

I'm trying to encrypt a password to be stored across multiple instances of my program, but it needs to be able to be decrypted by all users on the machine. I have already looked around for options, and had [javaDPAPI](http://jdpapi.sourceforge.net/) recommended to me. However, this only seems to encrypt based on the current user context.

Based on [microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptprotectdata) there seems to be a way to do this, but I am not sure how to do this and I am not very familiar with java and have never done something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Boolean in the second constructor of DataProtector mentioned [here](http://jdpapi.sourceforge.net/jdpapi-java/apidocs/index.html) to `true`.

This needs some adaptation in the class you linked too:

changing `this.protector = new DataProtector()` to

`this.protector = new DataProtector(true)` should do it, I think.

You could even add a project unique "entropy" byte array so that only someone knowing that entropy could decrypt the secret, and other programs cannot. This is also part of the original Microsoft design.